# Why is my callback not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This method runs at `node server`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const fs = require("fs");
const connectDb = require("./config/db");

const __init__ = (local = false) => {
  fs.writeFile(
    "./config/default.json",
    `{
        "mongoURI": ${
          local
            ? `"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"`
            : `"mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@abc-xxghh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`
        }
      }`,

    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }

      connectDb();
    }
  );
};

__init__(true);
```

The problem is that if originally `mongoURI: 127.0.0.1:27017`, and if I do `__init__(false)`, Node will try to connect to `127.0.0.1:27017`, when it should be connecting to `+srv` uri.

If I run `__init__(false)` AGAIN, then it will connect to appropriate link.

Likewise, if I then run `__init__(true)`, it will connect to `srv+` when it should be connecting to local, and if I run `__init__(true)` again, only then it will connect to local.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using the callback as Im supposed to, no?

---

Edit:

```
//config/db
// for mongoDB connection
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// require the directory
const config = require("config");
// get all contents of JSON file
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("connecting to mongodb", db);
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    console.log("Mongo DB connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("unable to connect to mongodb");
    console.log(err.message);
    //exit if failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDb;
```

---

I've even tried doing the following:

```
.....
  console.log("Developing locally:", local);

  // require the directory
  const config = require("config");
  // get all contents of JSON file
  const db = config.get("mongoURI");
  connectDb(db);
.....
```

But it still reads the old value

Comment: what is the node version and OS?

Comment: Could you add also `./config/db`. I think that is doing the require on startup so you are reading the file before the write

Comment: node v12.10.0, MacOS Mojave

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on execution order since the `require` is sync

The order now is:

1. `const connectDb = require("./config/db");`
2. `const config = require("config");`
3. `const db = config.get("mongoURI");` // this has the OLD VALUE
4. `fs.writeFile(...`
5. `await mongoose.connect(db, {` // this is using the OLD REFERENCE

So you need to change your `connectDb` function like this:

```js
const connectDb = async () => {
  const config = require("config");
  // get all contents of JSON file
  const db = config.get("mongoURI");

  try {
    console.log("connecting to mongodb", db);
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    console.log("Mongo DB connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("unable to connect to mongodb");
    console.log(err.message);
    //exit if failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Anyway, I think this is not a nicer way to load config based on the environment, so I would suggest improving it using factory pattern.

Comment: This doesnt work, I've already tried reposition the `const db = config.get("mongoURI");`. It still has the old value for some reason. I have a feeling the old value is loaded when `connectDb` is required, regardless of when `connectDb` is called

Comment: I moved in the function the `require("config")`, this is loading the file

Comment: Could you retry? [Looking the code](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/blob/master/lib/config.js) of the `config` module it is loading the `default.json` in sync with `require` function

Answer (score 0):

Your code for URL local vs srv+ is correct. Problem i could see is placement of method connectDb();

```
fs.writeFile("fir arg - URL", "second -content", third - error fun {});
```

where in your code after function, connectDb() is placed after error fun. After it should be closed.